# If $a \equiv b$ (mod 2n), then $a^2 \equiv b^2$ (mod 4n)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How would I go about proving: *If* $a \equiv b$ *(mod 2n), then* $a^2 \equiv b^2$ *(mod 4n)*?

I already tried proving $a+b = 2nk$ for some integer k, and that was pretty straightforward. But when I try to prove $a-b = 2nk$, I don't know what algebraic trick I need in order to get it to $a^2 - b^2 = 4nz$.

Comment: We have $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. Now note that $a+b$ is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a-b=2nk$ , where $k$ is an integer. So, $a-b$ is even.

$a=b+2nk$, so $a+b=2b+2nk$ is also even.

Then $a+b=2m$ where $m$ is an integer.

Now $a^2-b^2=2nk\times 2m$. Hence the result.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ 2n\mid a-b\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{2\mid a+b}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}2(2n)\mid (a-b)(\color{#c00}{a+b}) = a^2-b^2$

Comment: How do you show that  $\ 2n\mid a-b\,\Rightarrow\,{2\mid a+b}$. Is that an obvious statement? Maybe it is easier to justify the implication ${2\mid a-b}\,\Rightarrow\,{2\mid a+b}$, since it is clear that $2n\mid a-b\,$ implies both $2 \mid a -b $ and $n \mid a - b $,  i.e $2n$ being a factor of $a-b$ implies both $2$ and $n$ are factors of $a-b$ . Thanks.

Comment: @John Yes. Said modly: $\,a\equiv b\ $ mod $\,2n\,$ so also mod $2$  where  $\,a\equiv b\equiv -b\ $

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For some $k \in \mathbb Z$, we know $a = b + 2nk$. Compute $a^2$.